# How to change a thermal printer’s Bluetooth baud rate?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to print image using thermal printer through Bluetooth from Android device.

I connect Android phone to printer (printer model: [XP-318B/XP-318BM](https://www.xprintertech.com/xp-365b)) through Bluetooth then by using [BluetoothPrint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mate.bluetoothprint&hl=en&gl=US) app I send command to print image, the printer started to print a part of image then it stopped for half second and than it resume printer then it stops for half second then resume and it continues like this until it finish printing the image, white rows appear at the places which the printer was stopping as in the image.

First, I thought it was a programming issue, so I connect the printer though USB and then printed the same image it perfectly printed, so I'm thinking it is the baud rate of the printer's Bluetooth.
I search for two days with out any good results  how to change the baud rate.

I found these tutorials, but I couldn't change the baud rate .

- “[Instruction of Change Baud Rate for Bluetooth Printer (To 115200bps](https://www.ocominc.com/news/14090418291348.html))”
- “[How to Set Baud Rate for 58mm Thermal Printer](https://www.ocominc.com/news/How-to-Set-Baud-Rate-for-58mm-Thermal-Printer.html)”

What can I do?

[image: image 1]

Comment: You state, "I found these tutorials, but I couldn't change the baud rate." What did you try? Did you use *Bus Hound*? Did you use *IPrinter* software? Were there error messages? What else have you done?

Comment: Have you tried printing a lower resolution image?

Comment: I confess that I do not understand was a baudrate is, in relation to Bluetooth. The baudrate make a sense in relation to a serial interface, like RS-232. Bluetooth and USB have their own timing. Only when a serial converter is used, the baudrate has a significance.

Comment: Thank you for reply  DrMoishe Pippik.  yes, I did as the steps says even Bus Hound software said complete after pressing run button, but nothing changed, I also used Iprinter tool it connect to printer and I can print (print Test) from Iprinter, but when it comes to set baud rate nothing happen.

Comment: thank you for reply  Mokubai . it is already low, the printer has the capability to printer it I tried it with USB and it print the same image perfectly  fast and accurate.

Comment: Hi  Claude Frantz, yes even Bluetooth has Baud rate as serial.

Comment: Bluetooth is a pretty low bandwidth link to begin with. It can maybe do a theoretical maximum of 2 megabits while USB 2 can do 480 megabits.

Comment: Please connect the PC via Bluetooth to the printer. If it still does not work, the problem is unrelated to Android.

Comment: Mokubai - I have other printer (GOOJPRT  PT-210) work also with Bluetooth can print image without and mistake, this mean Bluetooth technology got the ability to print.

Comment: Robert - I did try with PC Bluetooth I got same result as android. yes it unrelated to android it related to hardware of Bluetooth (baud rate setting)